# WCF Service hard crashing Windows 2016

Tags: c#, vmware, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I have a web service running in IIS-10 on a Windows Server 2016 instance within a VM Hypervisor. A separate scheduled task calls functions of that web service during off peak times in order to retrieve status updates from a third party system. The scheduled task breaks the items that need to have statuses pulled into small batches and calls a function that retrieves / updates the records in parallel via Tasks and gives a return once all Tasks have completed.

Sometimes (every third time?), during this scheduled task, the app pool that the service is running on hangs. Log4Net stops logging, requests to the service do not get a response, IIS logging for the service is not updated with requests. There are no errors recorded in either my logs or in the windows event logs. When this happens, the app pool will stay in this state indefinitely. If I recycle the App Pool that the service is running on, the service will respond normally for ~30 seconds, and then the server will do a hard restart.

After the restart the event logs show the below error:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000139 (0x0000000000000003, 0xffffd60019506680, 0xffffd600195065d8, 0x0000000000000000).

The dmp file that is generated shows the same error code and identifies the file as ntoskrnl.exe.

All drivers are fully up to date. I have made sure all tasks and requests have timeouts. I have increased server resources past the point where that could be the cause. I have adjusted the batch size of items being processed.

I am out of troubleshooting ideas and would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: `0x139` is [`KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check---bug-check-0x139-kernel-security-check-failure), and the first parameter indicates this was due to a `LIST_ENTRY` corruption. In other words: you have a driver that contains a bug, no matter that it's up to date. ("ntoskrnl.exe" is just where the problem is detected, most probably not where the actual code at fault lives.)

Comment: Without going into a full kernel debugging tutorial, you could install [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/index), load up the dump (`windbg -z`) and do a quick `!analyze -v` to see if it can pinpoint the driver. Of course, since this is a VM, it's also quite possible the hypervisor itself is at fault (with the virtual hardware being "broken") and the analysis yields nothing useful (since you have no control over the drivers). But that's what you have Microsoft Support for.

Comment: Correction to the above: that's what you have VMWare support for. Microsoft won't handle support tickets about broken virtual hardware if they don't concern Hyper-V, since the third-party virtualization layer might be to blame.

Comment: A kernel component has corrupted a critical data structure.  The corruption
could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would close this out in case anyone else has this very specific issue.

Digging through the dump, BHDRVX64.SYS (Symantec Antivirus) was on the stack immediately before the crash.

A 4 days later Symantec pushed an update https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.INFO4367.html with a fix for the issue.

** If you hit a similar issue to this, start by uninstalling antivirus and seeing if the issue persists. After that, work through the list of kernel level processes returned by the 'fltmc' command in admin command prompt.